# ssh to another machine, by giving password

Tags: linux, ssh

I am able to ssh to another Linux by `ssh -q username@xxx.xx.xx.xxx`. But am not able to ssh by giving the password.

e.g. `[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx tmp]# ssh -q -P password username@xxx.xx.xx.xxx 'uname -a'`.

So tried removing -q. I got the following result.

```
[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx tmp]# ssh -P password username@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ssh: Could not resolve hostname password: Name or service not known.
```

The password is correct, is there anything I missed out.

Comment: What ssh client are you using? I'm not familiar with one that has a `-P` option or accepts a password on the command line.

Comment: If the first command didn't ask for any password and it still logged you in, it's not needed.----
It did prompt for the password.
I am able to login into the machine via putty using that password too.
If not - P, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try sshpass tool :

```
yum install sshpass -y
```

then

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@ip_address
```

Comment: Don't use such a tool, it spells out "major security risk" all over it.

Comment: Security risk is up to the user to assess. You can mention that it's a problem but that doesn't mean that the answer is incorrect.

Comment: the security risk is not his/her problem here , because she already  asked for option to pass  the password as "clear text" , she didn't mentioned it will used in prod. server to advice her to use encrypted/key based ssh access for example... or may be she is trying to scripting or testing ..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id), which will allow you to authenticate ssh connections using a key file stored on your client instead of entering your password.

Please be careful about storing credentials on your device. If applicable, consider encrypting your system drive.

Answer (score 1):

`-P` is a deprecated option that tells ssh not to use a privileged port for the outbound connection.

It has nothing to do with specifying a password on the command line.

As others have pointed out, use public key authentication for passwordless SSH.

Answer (score 0):

@Anna
On many Linux distribtions that run openssh-server, you cannot login as root.
Login as root is a major security risk and as such many distributions disable it by default.

Also even if possible you don't want to use -P as an option with SSH so you can type the password before the connection is made. This is also a major security risk.

Use the command

```
ssh username@IPaddress
```

Unless you have any special configuration that is all you need.
If you still have problems try

```
ssh -vvv username@IPaddress
```

This will give you alot of information about the connection and hints to as why the connection is failing.

As to the error you are experiencing **Could not resolve hostname password: Name or service not known.** When i read the manual page for SSH it does not have a -P option, so SSH is trying to resolve

> password

which it cannot.

Use the command `ssh username@IPaddress` and don't worry about the password. If the system requires a password it will ask for it, if the system do not need a password you will just directly login.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you typing "-P"?. It's at least not standard if not entirely useless.

Now for the error, it clearly says,

> Could not resolve hostname password: Name or service not known.

What's your first deduction off of it?.

I'm assuming it should be enough to figure it out.

If the first command didn't asked for any password and it still logged you in, it's not needed.

Some reasons could be:

1. Password is in your ssh keychain.
2. It's password-less.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are trying to access a Debian box from a root prompt?
Recent versions of Debian do no allow that. Try accessing as a normal user, and change to root when you're in.